# Working With SQL Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two fields (StartTime and EndTime) both are varchar field (It was created before I  started)

```
Start Time        End time
{t '01:00:00'}  {t '21:30:00'}
{t '01:30:00'}  {t '09:00:00'}
{t '07:00:00'}  {t '11:30:00'}
{t '08:00:00'}  {t '19:00:00'}
{t '07:00:00'}  {t '11:00:00'}
```

I am creating a query to only get records where current time is between the start and end time.

for example if start time is 1am and end time is 9pm. And the time now is 11am it would get that record.

I am not sure how to do it with varchar fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If would just work if it's all in the **same** format and 24 hour time. As per ASCII codes...

```
{t '08:00:00'} <= {t '11:00:00'} <= {t '19:00:00'}
```

If you store `hh:mm:ss` not `{t 'hh:mm:ss'}`

```
08:00:00 <= 11:00:00 <= 19:00:00
```

No need to CAST to time etc if you're stuck with legacy code/data...

Edit, as per comment

If you want to cast then extract the real data from the fluff

```
CAST(SUBSTRING('{t ''01:00:00''}', 5, 8) AS time)
--OR
CAST('01:00:00' AS time)
```

Comment: Please tell us, how you convert/cast a datetime to a string of this format

Comment: I ended up using your {t '08:00:00'} <= {t '11:00:00'} <= {t '19:00:00'}  example.

Answer (score 0):

There another way to do this , I'll write sample query here.Hope it helps

```
SELECT * from TableName
WHERE right(CONVERT(datetime,starttime,103),7) = '01:00AM' and
      right(CONVERT(datetime,endtime,103),7) = '09:00PM' and
      right(CONVERT(datetime,getdate(),103),7) = '11:00AM'
```